Setting dependency only for specific configuration in Tuist like CocoaPods
I am newbie in Tuist.
I want to use this dependency only for Debug build setting. But I not found any setting about this in Tuist.
In Cocoapods, below code is work.
pod "HyperioniOS/Core", :configurations => ['Debug']
current Tuist version is 3.40.0
To be able to use Hyperion framework only in Debug build.
